# Pysvn installer fails to detect Python installation

Tags: python, windows-installer, pysvn

I have Python 2.7.2 installed in the default location, C:\Python27.
I've downloaded pysvn 2.7 from http://pysvn.tigris.org/project_downloads.html > Windows installation kits. Pysvn Windows installer aborts on

> pysvn requires Python 2.7 to be installed.
>
> Quitting installation

I've tried both installer files, py27-pysvn-svn1612-1.7.4-1321.exe and py27-pysvn-svn1615-1.7.5-1360.exe. Neither of them works.

How can I convince the installer that I have Python 2.7 installed?
How is the installer determining whether pysvn is installed or not?

Comment: Is the Python path set in your "Path" system variable?

Comment: Yes, PATH system variable contains C:\Python27\

Comment: Are you able to access Python by opening up the command prompt and typing "python"?

Comment: Yes, and 'where python' displays C:\Python27\python.exe.

Comment: Does the installer show any details during the installation that could help troubleshoot why its not finding it?

Comment: Nope, the described error message is the first and only indication of failure.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Did u perhaps install the 64-bit version of Python? If yes: Try the 32-bit installer.

Background: It seems like the 64-bit installer doesn't properly set the correct values in the windows registry (which is the place where PySVN tries to find Python).

Comment: I reinstalled Python 2.7, now as a 32-bit version. After that Pysvn installation works like a charm.

Comment: @Andreas Yes, that is the case. However I need python in 64 bits. Can I install pysvn with 64 bits python?

Answer (score 2):

I tried this and it worked perfectly:

Copy HKLM\SOFTWARE​\Pyt​ho​n\Pyth​onCore\2​.7\In​​stallPath to HKCU\SOFTWARE​\Pyt​ho​n\Pyth​onCore\2​.7\In​​stallPath.

Same link as above, but a different solution is offered within the thread. It is a problem with the pysvn 32-bit installer looking in the wrong (?) place in the Registry for the installed Python version.

Edit: The 32-bit module still didn't work correctly with the 64-bit Python. The only solution for this is to use 32-bit Python with the module.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to copy the the registry keys from **HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\​SOFTWARE\Python** to **HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\​SOFTWARE\Wow6432Nod​e\Python**

http://pysvn.tigris.org/ds/viewMessage.do?dsForumId=1335&viewType=browseAll&dsMessageId=2719385

Comment: I tried this approach with PIL. I ran into some serious error messages when trying to load the Image library. Finally, I replaced Python 64-bit installation with the 32-bit one. After that, PIL worked just fine.

Comment: Most likely the pysvn binaries are built for 32-bit Python and so this solution, while getting you past the "can't find Python problem" will be DOA when you try to actually use pysvn.

Answer (score 0):

My case was a bit different. Since my Anaconda install was for Python 3.6, no matter what I did I wasn't able to install PySvn (never got detected).

So since PySvn last release is for Python 3.5, I've created a conda env for Python 3.5.

Open Anaconda prompt and type: `conda create -n *myenv* python=3.5`

Then, open the win prompt and type `regedit`.

In `regedit`, under `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\​SOFTWARE\Python\PythonCore\` I changed the name of the folder from `3.6` to `3.5`. Additionally, in `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\​SOFTWARE\Python\PythonCore\3.5\InstallPath` I changed the value of Anaconda's default folder to my Anaconda's env folder `(C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\env\*myenv*)`.

Then I ran the installed and it worked fined. After installed, I remade the changes in the system registry to the original ones.

Now I can import Pysvn, inside my conda env, without any problems.