# Python 3.5 for 64 bit windows not setting the windows registry correctly

Tags: python, windows, pysvn

I want to install pySVN(py35-pysvn-svn1814-1.8.0-1667.exe) windows binary kits.But after installing python 3.5(64 bit) on my windows,it is not setting the windows registry correctly.
Im getting the following message,

```
pysvn requires Python 3.5 to be installed.

Quitting installation
```

I given PATH correctly and it is working in cmd prompt when i give 'python' there.
How can I solve this issue?

Comment: The underlying question is "how does pysvn installer checks for Python version?". For a starter, do you have multiple versions installed?

Comment: I found something [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8941706/pysvn-installer-fails-to-detect-python-installation). Now i cant find 32 bit version of python 3.5 anywhere. Can anyone suggest some ideas?

Comment: @Stefano Yes i have both Pythion  2.7 and 3.5 versions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK pysvn doesn't work with 64 bit Python on Windows. This is because the underlying subversion library is compiled for 32 bit only.

You can get 32 bit Python 3.5 here: https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.5.0/python-3.5.0.exe

Comment: pysvn is not released for win64 with python 2.7 and python 3.5.